# Can't make delete/update/edit unique to the users post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Hi guys I have a slight problem may be a hard one I have tried to do this with the following code in the index segment of my review controller:

```
var Info = db.tblReviews.Include(x => x.tblGame).Where(UserInfo => UserInfo.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).ToList();
return View(Info);
```

and within the first create of the review controller I have applied:

```
ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName");
return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });
```

My problem is I am trying to allow people to write reviews on games, av got it so that all users that post a game are unique and the games are only viewable by there own accounts but when it comes to edit/deleting/updating I cant get it so that the user posted the game review can only delete/update/edit there own games and not the other users.

For example I have two made up users called sham and bam, each user can see the games that they have posted on the review page but when it comes to edting/updating and deleting the review both user delete/edit and update each others posts.

This is my review controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using GameTest.Models;

namespace GameTest.Controllers
{ 
    public class ReviewController : Controller
    {
        private gamezoneDBEntities db = new gamezoneDBEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Review/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var Info = db.tblReviews.Include(x => x.tblGame).Where(UserInfo => UserInfo.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).ToList();
            return View(Info); 
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName");
            return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Review/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(tblReview tblreview)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tblReviews.Add(tblreview);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName", tblreview.GameIDFK);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName", tblreview.GameIDFK);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Review/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(tblReview tblreview)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tblreview).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName", tblreview.GameIDFK);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Review/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            return View(tblreview);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Review/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {            
            tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
            db.tblReviews.Remove(tblreview);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

If you require more please let me know thanks

much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer this without being able to see your data structure, but I will try to help.

I can see in your `Index()` action that you are getting the user name to retrieve games. So, it looks like your review object stores some reference to the user that created it.

Therefore, on update/delete, just retrieve the user name again, and if it doesn't match the user name on the review object, don't perform the action.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //See if this review id was created by the current user
        if(!db.tblReviews.Any(UserInfo => UserInfo.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name) && UserInfo.Id == id))
        {
            //Redirect the user away from this edit page, they can't edit this one.
        }

        tblReview tblreview = db.tblReviews.Find(id);
        ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(db.tblGames, "GameID", "GameName", tblreview.GameIDFK);
        return View(tblreview);
    }
```